# UICollectionViewCell gets squished after running in simulator

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have designed a collection view cell, seen below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFAWz.png],

When I try to run it in the simulator it is getting resized, as below:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA5AH.png]

I have not set any constraints to the collection view and didn't resize it programatically.  How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make it shown correctly,
you should use size class or constrains, since Xcode will resize it for all models, not knowing your thoughts.

You can’t leave it there without adding constrains